# Django: Retrieve a model Queryset that created today but has no entries before

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Lets take a situation,

```
class A(models.Model): 
   customer = models.FK(User)
   created = models.DateTimeField()
   ...
```

I need to fetch all the rows created today but only the rows that is created for the first time against each customer. 
Suppose a customer made an entry yesterday and today, we do not want to include it. But if the customer is making an entry for the first time today in the table it has to be included.

This can be achieved using two different querying steps , one to fetch all entries today then check if the customer is made that entry for the first time in this table using next step of query.

What I am searching for is a better optimized way to achieve this. Is there a better solution, a better way to use Django ORM?

Comment: How do you know _when_ a record was created? Do you have a DateTimeField column that tracks that? Databases typically don't give you that information for free...

Comment: Yes I have a created column. Which is a datetimefield. Sorry I will edit the model definition.